If $g_1, g_2\in\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ are equal locally $\mu$-almost everywhere, then $T_{g_1}=T_{g_2}$.
Background
Suppose that $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is an arbitrary measure space, that $p$ satisfies $1\leq p<+\infty$, and that $q$ is defined by $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Let $g$ belong to $\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$. Then $fg$ is integrable whenever $f$ belongs to $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ (by Hölder's inequality), and so the formula
\begin{align*}
    T_g(f) = \int fgd\mu
\end{align*}
defines a linear functional $T_g$ on $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.
Denote $T$ the map from $\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ to $\left(L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)\right)^*$ that takes the function $g$ to the functional $T_g$ defined above.
My Question
Now, it is clear that if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are equal almost everywhere, then $T_{g_1}=T_{g_2}$. However, the book I am reading pointed out that, in case $q=+\infty$, we have if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are equal locally almost everywhere then $T_{g_1}=T_{g_2}$. I want to prove this claim, but got stuck.
My Attempt So Far

I want to consider first the case when $fg_1$ and $fg_2$ are nonnegative. Let $A=\{x\in X:(fg_1)(x) \neq (fg_2)(x)\}$. Let $h$ be the function defined by
\begin{align*}
h(x)=
\begin{cases}
+\infty\quad &\text{if $x\in A$},\\
0\quad &\text{if $x\neq A$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Define $\{h_n\}$ by $h_n=n\chi_{A}$. Then $h(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n(x)$ for all $x\in X$. So $\int hd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int h_nd\mu$

I got stuck here. What I wanted to do (but failed so far) is to show that $\int hd\mu=0$. Then in view of $fg_1\leq fg_2+h$, this would imply that $\int fg_1d\mu\leq\int fg_2d\mu + \int hd\mu = \int fg_2d\mu$. Then analogously,  $\int fg_2d\mu\leq\int fg_1d\mu$, and we would have been done.
Could someone please help me out? Thank you very much in advance!

A property holds locally $\mu$-almost everywhere if the set of points at which it fails to hold is locally $\mu$-null.
A set $N$ is called locally $\mu$-null if for each set $A$ that belongs to $\mathscr{A}$ and satisfies $\mu(A)<+\infty$ the set $A\bigcap N$ is $\mu$-null.

Your approach cannot work: if the integral of $h$ is zero, this means that $A$ is a nullset and $g_1=g_2$ almost everywhere.
The crucial aspect of this is that you are evaluating your functionals on functions of $L^1$. And an integrable function is nonzero on a $\sigma$-finite set, regardless of the measure space.
Indeed, if $f\in L^1(X)$, then $\{f\ne0\}=\bigcup_nF_n$, where
$$
F_n=\Big\{x:\ |f(x)|\geq\frac1n\Big\}.
$$
We have
$$
\mu(F_n)=\int_{F_n}1\,d\mu=n\,\int_{F_n}\frac1n\,d\mu\leq n\,\int_X|f|\,d\mu<\infty.
$$
By hypothesis, on each $F_n$ we have $g_1=g_2$ almost everywhere. Then (replacing the $F_n$ with a disjoint union and using Dominated Convergence to write the integral as a sum over the union)
$$
T_{g_1}f=\int_X fg_1=\sum_n\int_{F_n}fg_1=\sum_n\int_{F_n}fg_2=\int_Xfg_2=T_{g_2}f. 
$$
